# How can I broadcast video using VLC?

Tags: streaming, vlc-media-player, live-broadcast

I'd like to broadcast video, from my server to my client machines in the same lan.

I found this tutorial online, but I can't seem to find the Channel menu he's talking about. I'm using VLC 1.1.4 The Luggage.

Thanks for the help.

http://esm.cs.cmu.edu/support/broadcaster/pages/5.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you gave is a sublink of [ESM Broadcaster](http://esm.cs.cmu.edu/download/index.html). You need to install it to see that menu.